# Replacing values based on conditional using pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataset similar to this one:

```
d = {
   'col1': [1,2,3,4,2,4,1,3,5,3,2,2,1,5], 
   'col2': [2,1,5,2,4,1,3,3,3,2,2,4,2,1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

It is:

```
    col1    col2
0   1       2
1   2       1
2   3       5
3   4       2
4   2       4
5   4       1
6   1       3
7   3       3
8   5       3
9   3       2
10  2       2
11  2       4
12  1       2
13  5       1
```

I'd like to 'categorize' the content of the cells of ONLY ONE column, let's say col2. For instance if the value of a cell is 2 or 3 or 4, I'd like to replace it with the value 7. I have tried the following:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    if row.col2==2 or row.P28==3 or row.P28==4:
        df1.set_value(row, 'P28', 7)
```

But the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

is returned. I am not sure of why I am getting this error and how should I use any of the suggested functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily, You don't need to loop:

```
mask = df['col2'].isin([2,3,4])  # Create a boolean mask of the condition
df.loc[mask, 'col2'] = 7         # Replace values based on boolean mask

df
#     col1  col2
# 0      1     7
# 1      2     1
# 2      3     5
# 3      4     7
# 4      2     7
# 5      4     1
# 6      1     7
# 7      3     7
# 8      5     7
# 9      3     7
# 10     2     7
# 11     2     7
# 12     1     7
# 13     5     1
```

Comment: I like this. I’d use the method where though, personal preference . df.assign(col2=df.col2.where(mask, 7))

Comment: Brilliant! I am using python since a year now, but I still can't think pythonic. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace using dictionary

```
d = dict.fromkeys([2,3,4], 7)
df['col2'] = df.col2.replace(d)

    col1    col2
0   1   7
1   2   1
2   3   5
3   4   7
4   2   7
5   4   1
6   1   7
7   3   7
8   5   7
9   3   7
10  2   7
11  2   7
12  1   7
13  5   1
```

Comment: This is great. I must remember to start using fromkeys

Comment: @piRSquared, can't believe you said that! Wish you a very happy new year btw

Comment: Don’t be so surprised. You’re awesome. Happy new year to you as well.

Comment: This one is brilliant as well, didn't know fromkeys. Thanks a lot.